# how many nodes in an AWS EC2 instance?

Tags: amazon-ec2, nodes

How many master and worker nodes are there in an AWS EC2 instance? I am trying to create an EC2 instance with 1 master and 2 worker nodes, but couldn't find anything related to it.

Comment: Are you referring to [Amazon EMR](https://aws.amazon.com/documentation/emr/)? It is a managed Hadoop services that uses EC2 instances as master & worker nodes.

Answer (score 0):

I think you might not have a clear understanding of what an EC2 instance is.

Think of an EC2 instance as a virtual machine. Nothing less, nothing more.

You can install the OS and application you want on it, thus make one EC2 a master for a SQL database and another EC2 instance for it's slave for exemple.

Hope this helps.